# Generics wildcarding with both "extends" and "super"

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am working on a project where services need to be added to a component. The `Service` class is an interface without any methods. Here is an example how my services work:

```
public interface Service { }

public interface CarWash extends Service {
  void washCar(Car car);
}

public interface CarRepair extends Service {
  void repairCar(Car car);
}
```

Now there are many implementations of these services. A single class may implement multiple services, as this garage class:

```
public class Garage implements CarWash, CarRepair {
  @Override
  public void washCar(Car car) { /* .. */ }
  @Override
  public void repairCar(Car car) { /* .. */ }
}
```

When adding a service to a component, I do not want to need to use the service for all tasks, but for example use the `Garage` only for washing cars (`CarWash`) but not for repairing them (`CarRepair`). Therefore I specify the tasks as classes, just like this:

```
void addService(Service service, Class<? extends Service> task);
```

To check whether the service could actually perform the task, I used generics:

```
<T extends Service> addService(T service, Class<? super T> task);
```

This works well but does not check if the provided task is actually a task (a class that implements `Service`), so this would work:

```
addService(myTask, Object.class);
```

**I am looking for a way to specify that `service` needs to implement (extend) the `task` AND the `task` is extending the `Service` interface,** like this *(does not compile)*:

```
<T extends Service> addService(T service, Class<? super T extends Service> task);
```

Comment: How about: `<T extends Service, S extends T> void addService(S service, Class<T> clazz);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that `<T extends Service, S extends T> void addService(S service, Class<T> clazz)` sounds like it meets your criteria:

```
public static class Foo {                                                                                   
  public interface Service { }                                                                          

  public interface CarWash extends Service {                                                            
    void washCar();                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                     

  public interface CarRepair extends Service {                                                          
    void repairCar();                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                     

  static <T extends Service, S extends T> void addService(S service, Class<T> clazz) {}                 

  public static void main(String[] args) {                                                              
    addService(null, CarWash.class);  // Fine.                                                                  
    addService(null, Object.class);   // Compilation error.                                                          
  }
}
```

(I added some statics and removed `Car` from method signatures, since I don't have a definition of those to compile)

Comment: Works, thank you very much! The only problem I am having is the varargs that force all array elements to be of the same type, and therefore I cannot write `addService(null, CarWash.class, CarRepair.class);`.

Comment: Well now you didn't ask about varargs... that sounds like a case where you don't really want to be using an array anyway, and should prefer use of an Iterable, e.g. `static <T extends Service, S extends T> void addService(S service, Iterable<? extends Class<? extends T>> clazzes)`. But I don't think that'd do the right thing with respect to `service` implementing all of those classes. I think in that case you'd actually be better defining explicit overloads with 1, 2, 3 etc class parameters. Sounds messy though.

Comment: I agree. I think it is fine to leave it as one parameter and call the method multiple times to add a service for multiple tasks though, just as you have it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may also be fine, depending on how you use the type of `service`:

```
<T extends Service> void addService(T service, Class<T> task)
```

If the `service` is a subtype of the type represented by `task`, then it can always be upcasted.

```
addService(new Garage(), CarWash.class); // OK, Garage is a CarWash
```

---

> The only problem I am having is the varargs that force all array elements to be of the same type, and therefore I cannot write `addService(null, CarWash.class, CarRepair.class);`

This is actually a difficult problem for Java generics. (C++ can do this with [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), which is a feature Java is very unlikely to get.)

So one way you can solve this in Java is with run time validation e.g.:

```
<T extends Service> void addService(
        T service, Class<? super T> tasks...) {
    for(Class<? super T> task : tasks)
        if(!Service.class.isAssignableFrom(tasks))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

(Or use `Class<? extends Service>` and check that `task.isInstance(service)`.)

But I know we don't really like that. ; )

Java does have something called an [intersection type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9) (where if we have a type `<? extends T & U>`, the `T & U` part is called an intersection type), but an intersection type cannot combine `super` and `extends` and they are otherwise pretty limited in what else they can do.